# I want to help with UI/UX design?

Tags: design

I wanna help with various apps that come bundled with elementary os.

I can help with UI/UX.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to help with Elementary OS in any way it is best to go to their [GitHub](https://github.com/elementary) page and look for open issues in their respective [repositories](https://github.com/elementary). There might be something UI/UX related you can contribute to.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section into their official web page for this. Just follow this link - https://elementary.io/get-involved#design